# Running a query within a class method

Tags: php, query

So i'm looking at 
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/database.html

I've used

```
$query = $this->EE->db->query("SELECT channel_name FROM exp_channels");
```

many times, but never within a class. and using $this-> causes issues. I'm no expert but how do i overcome this?

```
class Name
{
    public $variable;

    public function Something()
    {
         if($this->variable == "whatever")
           {
                //Run query to pull data based on $variable
                // This causes errors. I assume because $this is now something else.
                $this->EE->db->query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE...");
           }
    }
}
```

Message: Undefined property: Module::$EE

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to initialize global object like:

```
$this->EE =& get_instance();
```

Comment: Is this in the user guide somewhere?

Comment: It's mentioned in the [addon dev docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/index.html) and is used if you're building a plugin, extension, or module. It just makes a local reference to the EE super object.